# Can't access Leaflet map with Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, leaflet

When initialising a Leaflet map with Backbone.js I can't access this exact map anymore.

E.g.:

```
mapView.map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 10});
```

will result in

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'mapView.map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 10})')

The map is initialized via a separate view in a dashboard view like:

```
this.mapView = new MapView();
    $(this.$el).find('.content').append(this.mapView.el).find('.map').addClass('full').css({
        'height': $(window).height() / 2
    });
```

This view looks like:

```
var MapView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template(""),
    render: function ()
    {
        this.$el.html(this.template());

        this.map = L.map(this.el).setView([48.00786, 13.17989], 8);

        this.map = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: 'OpenStreetMap &copy; Mitwirkende der <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
        }).addTo(this.map);

        return this;
    }
});
```

I can access the map object by just console.log'ing it. The result looks like:

> _animated: true
>   _bgBuffer: HTMLDivElement
>   _clearBgBufferTimer: 4
>   _container: HTMLDivElement
>   _initHooksCalled: true
>   _leaflet_events: Object
>   _leaflet_id: 20
>   _limitedUpdate: function s() {var a=arguments;return n?(o=!0,void 0):(n=!0,setTimeout(function(){n=!1,o&&(s.apply(i,a),o=!1)},e),t.apply(i,a),void 0);}
>   _map: Object
>   _tileContainer: HTMLDivElement
>   _tileImg: HTMLImageElement
>   _tiles: Object
>   _tilesToLoad: 0
>   _url: "http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
>   options: Object
>   **proto**: Object

But why am I not able to access this map afterwards?

Thanks!

Comment: `mapView.map.locate` would suggest that you're expecting to find a `mapView` variable when you only have a `mapView` property in one of your views. And don't `$(this.$el)`, just use `this.$el`; [`this.$`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar) is the same as `this.$el.find`.

Comment: Thanks ;) I see your point, but mapView and mapView are two (well, badly named, but anyway) variables. The MapView itself has a property valled mapView, in the router (where I need to render map view) var mapView is initialised like var mapView = view.mapView.render(); - sorry...

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I just moved the whole map thing to the view and did not separate the map into another view. That's probably not the finest way to do this but it does it's job quite well.